# Bootstrap navbar-brand logo/svg positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, navbar

Here is what i want

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfA0m.png

Here's what I came up with:

**HTML**

```
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <div class="eye">

  <svg width="50" height="50" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 380 296" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
  <g>
  <defs>
  <rect x="0.922" y="1" width="378.156" height="302" />
  </defs>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M189.967,1C121.452,1,52.925,50.029,0.915,148.048
  c52.01,98.071,120.537,147.047,189.052,147.047c68.58,0,137.108-48.977,189.117-147.047C327.075,50.029,258.547,1,189.967,1
  L189.967,1z M189.967,253.091c-49.804,0-100.369-37.947-140.785-105.043C89.598,81.017,140.163,43.004,189.967,43.004
  c49.856,0,100.435,38.013,140.85,105.044C290.402,215.145,239.823,253.091,189.967,253.091L189.967,253.091z M190.952,90.496
  c-33.935,0-61.505,27.57-61.505,61.505c0,34.03,27.57,61.504,61.505,61.504c34.03,0,61.6-27.474,61.6-61.504
  C252.552,118.066,224.982,90.496,190.952,90.496L190.952,90.496z M189.967,106.043" />
  </g>
  </g>
  </svg>

  </div>
  </a>
```

**CSS**

```
.eye {
position: absolute;
background-color: black;
width: 65px;
height: 65px;
top: 0;
left: 17px;
}

.eye svg {
margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
fill: white;
}

.navbar-brand {
float: left;
height: 50px;
padding: 15px 50px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 20px;
}
```

Is there another way of doing it? Cause I feel like my way is wrong.

**Demo**:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avPgMJ

Comment: You want logo to overflow navbar like in your image?

Comment: Yes, here's the demo of what I came up with http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/avPgMJ but I don't know if I'm doing it right, I was hoping a pro could tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example based on the image you posted. The vast majority of this is just styling and a minimal amount of structural adjustments mostly to offset the content under the SVG so there isn't an overlap at all.

See working Snippet.

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid #222;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.eye {
  background-color: #222;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  z-index: 1051.
}
.eye svg {
  margin: 25px;
  fill: #7D0000;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-left {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    border: none;
    background: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nv" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <div class="eye">

          <svg width="50" height="50" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 380 296" xml:space="preserve">
            <g>
              <g>
                <defs>
                  <rect x="0.922" y="1" width="378.156" height="302" />
                </defs>
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M189.967,1C121.452,1,52.925,50.029,0.915,148.048
   c52.01,98.071,120.537,147.047,189.052,147.047c68.58,0,137.108-48.977,189.117-147.047C327.075,50.029,258.547,1,189.967,1
   L189.967,1z M189.967,253.091c-49.804,0-100.369-37.947-140.785-105.043C89.598,81.017,140.163,43.004,189.967,43.004
   c49.856,0,100.435,38.013,140.85,105.044C290.402,215.145,239.823,253.091,189.967,253.091L189.967,253.091z M190.952,90.496
   c-33.935,0-61.505,27.57-61.505,61.505c0,34.03,27.57,61.504,61.505,61.504c34.03,0,61.6-27.474,61.6-61.504
   C252.552,118.066,224.982,90.496,190.952,90.496L190.952,90.496z M189.967,106.043" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>

        </div>
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nv">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem and glad I could help!